# Flutter Abstract class provide defaults for getter

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract

I have an abstract class where I want two fields two have a `default`-value. But you should also be able to override them. Currently I have this:

```
abstract class Dummy {
  // ...
  Duration get progressBarAnimationDuration;
  Curve get progressBarAnimationCurve;
}
```

How can I give a `default` to these fields and also have the option to `override` them if needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nothing special about it being an abstract class -

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  Duration get progressBarAnimationDuration => const Duration(seconds: 1);
  Curve get progressBarAnimationCurve => Curves.easeInOut;
}

class SubClass implements SuperClass {
  @override
  Duration get progressBarAnimationDuration => const Duration(seconds: 2);
  
  @override
  Curve get progressBarAnimationCurve => Curves.easeIn;
}
```

Comment: my VSCode was tripping... Tried tried that before but it didn't let me. One a new start, it is working as expected. Thank you :)